# Add a 3-d java sphere to a single tab of my swing

Tags: java

I have several tabs on my swing application and I want one of the tabs to hold a 3d sphere or any 3-d object for that matter ? Is this possible using the [java3d](http://www.java3d.org/index.html) api. If so some pointers would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to combine Java3d and Swing.

The best way is to use [JCanvas3D](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.0/com/sun/j3d/exp/swing/JCanvas3D.html) which provides lightweight capability to Java3d.

You can also mix lightweight(swing) and heavyweight(Java3D) components on the same screen if you keep them in separate containers.

Check [this](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs3283/ftp/Java/swingConnect/archive/tech_topics_arch/mixing/mixing.html) page for more information.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Will definitely go through it